# Set custom findBugs rules, disable failsOnViolation using qulice-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, findbugs, qulice

I want to use [qulice-maven-plugin](http://www.qulice.com/qulice-maven-plugin/usage.html) and I do not want to use the default **findBugs** rules but to set my custom once. Is that possible?
- Also, I do not want qulice-maven-plugin to fail on checkstyle violations, but I do no want to disable the plugin. How to change the default qulice-maven-plugin, checkstyle configuration?

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.qulice</groupId>
      <artifactId>qulice-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.16.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <license>file:${basedir}/LICENSE.txt</license>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: First i would remove the license configuration based on the docs it is the default. Furthermore i would ask the creators of the qulice-maven-plugin ...

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to override the rules in qulice. The basic idea behind it is that it has a set of rules that are not changeable. So each project that uses qulice looks more/less the same.

You can only disable qulice using regexp (checkstyle:.*), like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.qulice</groupId>
    <artifactId>qulice-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.16.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <license>file:./LICENSE.txt</license>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>findbugs:~com.qulice.foo.M.*</exclude>
            <exclude>findbugs:com.qulice.foo.Bar</exclude>
            <exclude>findbugs:.*</exclude>
            <exclude>checkstyle:.*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

So you can achieve only the second requirement - build won't fail if checkstyle fails.
For findbugs you would need to use `SuppressFBWarnings` (from `edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations`) like this: `@SuppressFBWarnings("JLM_JSR166_UTILCONCURRENT_MONITORENTER")`

Comment: thanks. But I have some rules that are not necessary and which cause a lot of noise in the reports. I need bigger power of configuration. For now I think qulice will not fulfill the requirements of my project, it will not reduce the complexity of my maven script but will even make it more complex and will cause more troubles.

Comment: @Xelian just use Checkstyle and PMD directly and configure them the way you need